# UITesting maps in Xcode

Tags: xcode, dictionary, uitest

I'm currently try to UITest a map and tap on a pin. I 'translated' this code I found [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24932) to swift to try it but didn't work:

```
XCUIElementQuery * mapContents = [[app.windows elementBoundByIndex: 0] otherElements ];
XCUIElement * pin = nil;
for (XCUIElement * element in mapContents.allElementsBoundByIndex)
{
    CGSize elementSize = [element frame].size;
    if ((elementSize.width == 48) && (elementSize.height == 48))
    {
        pin = element;
        break;
    }
}
```

I realised that the map element doesn't even have children. The only interaction I've managed to make was the presented [here](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7/)

```
app.maps.element.pinchWithScale(1.5, velocity: 1)
```

It works but pinching doesn't test anything, how have you guys UItested maps?